Error in Namespace due to flutter_beacon package
I am trying to scan the ibeacon devices using flutter_beacon: latest package. However, whenever I try to add this package and simply do ```flutter run`` I am encountering this problem.
What I have tried so far:

changing and confirming the name of the project.
the problem starts coming soon after installing the package.
I have also tried other Flutter packages for ibeacons

error:
   Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option .. ```

Note: I'm open to using a different package
Github: issue id 1

if you are using VSCode open Explorer panel in the left side then open Dependencies search for flutter_beacon folder and open it

then go to android -> build.gradle you'll find it like
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

edit it to this
android {
    namespace "com.flutterbeacon" // add this line
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

finally, build your project again
